# XLS sort xml nodes by attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I tried to sort xml nodes by an attribute value but although I sorted them correctly I am not able to get the same xml changed as output.

**Source:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enumeration attributeTypeId="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area" name="Área">
    <literal externalValue="Enol" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l3" name="Enol"/>
    <literal externalValue="Pasivo" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l8" name="Pasivo"/>
    <literal externalValue="Proyectos" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l5" name="Proyectos"/>
    <literal externalValue="Servicios" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l10" name="Servicios"/>
    <literal default="true" externalValue="---" id="---" name="---" null="true" />
    <literal externalValue="Activo" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l7" name="Activo"/>
    <literal externalValue="Canales y MMP" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l9" name="Canales y MMP"/>
    <literal externalValue="Arquitectura" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l4" name="Arquitectura"/>
    <literal externalValue="Centro Información" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l6" name="Centro Información"/>
    <literal externalValue="Desarrollo Corporativo" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l2" name="Desarrollo Corporativo"/>
    <literal externalValue="Producción y Sistemas" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l1" name="Producción y Sistemas"/>
</enumeration>
```

**XSL:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="enumeration/literal">
        <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <!-- this should be different, I tried with select="current()" too -->
      </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output expected:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enumeration attributeTypeId="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area" name="Área">
    <literal default="true" externalValue="---" id="---" name="---" null="true" />
    <literal externalValue="Activo" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l7" name="Activo"/>
    <literal externalValue="Arquitectura" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l4" name="Arquitectura"/>
    <literal externalValue="Canales y MMP" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l9" name="Canales y MMP"/>
    <literal externalValue="Centro Información" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l6" name="Centro Información"/>
    <literal externalValue="Desarrollo Corporativo" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l2" name="Desarrollo Corporativo"/>
    <literal externalValue="Enol" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l3" name="Enol"/>
    <literal externalValue="Pasivo" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l8" name="Pasivo"/>
    <literal externalValue="Producción y Sistemas" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l1" name="Producción y Sistemas"/>
    <literal externalValue="Proyectos" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l5" name="Proyectos"/>
    <literal externalValue="Servicios" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l10" name="Servicios"/>
</enumeration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enumeration attributeTypeId="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area" name="Área">
  <literal externalValue="Enol" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l3" name="Enol"/>
  <literal externalValue="Pasivo" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l8" name="Pasivo"/>
  <literal externalValue="Proyectos" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l5" name="Proyectos"/>
  <literal externalValue="Servicios" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l10" name="Servicios"/>
  <literal default="true" externalValue="---" id="---" name="---" null="true" />
  <literal externalValue="Activo" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l7" name="Activo"/>
  <literal externalValue="Canales y MMP" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l9" name="Canales y MMP"/>
  <literal externalValue="Arquitectura" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l4" name="Arquitectura"/>
  <literal externalValue="Centro Información" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l6" name="Centro Información"/>
  <literal externalValue="Desarrollo Corporativo" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l2" name="Desarrollo Corporativo"/>
  <literal externalValue="Producción y Sistemas" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l1" name="Producción y Sistemas"/>
</enumeration>
```

And given XSLT sytlesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="enumeration">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="literal">
      <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Yields output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enumeration>
  <literal default="true" externalValue="---" id="---" name="---" null="true"/>
  <literal externalValue="Activo" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l7" name="Activo"/>
  <literal externalValue="Arquitectura" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l4" name="Arquitectura"/>
  <literal externalValue="Canales y MMP" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l9" name="Canales y MMP"/>
  <literal externalValue="Centro Información" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l6" name="Centro Información"/>
  <literal externalValue="Desarrollo Corporativo" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l2" name="Desarrollo Corporativo"/>
  <literal externalValue="Enol" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l3" name="Enol"/>
  <literal externalValue="Pasivo" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l8" name="Pasivo"/>
  <literal externalValue="Producción y Sistemas" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l1" name="Producción y Sistemas"/>
  <literal externalValue="Proyectos" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l5" name="Proyectos"/>
  <literal externalValue="Servicios" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l10" name="Servicios"/>
</enumeration>
```

I'm not entirely sure if you can sort by attribute value in a for-each loop. Also you should avoid using for-each loops and use templates instead.

Comment: Your first template is redundant.

Comment: @michael.hor257k you are right, but I always leave that in as a force of habit.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to achieve this is the following stylesheet. Adjust the template `match=` to your needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
  <xsl:template match="/enumeration[@attributeTypeId='com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area' and @name='Área']">
    <enumeration attributeTypeId="{@attributeTypeId}" name="{@name}">
      <xsl:for-each select="literal">
        <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </enumeration>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This results in

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<enumeration attributeTypeId="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area" name="&#xC1;rea">
  <literal default="true" externalValue="---" id="---" name="---" null="true"/>
  <literal externalValue="Activo" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l7" name="Activo"/>
  <literal externalValue="Arquitectura" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l4" name="Arquitectura"/>
  <literal externalValue="Canales y MMP" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l9" name="Canales y MMP"/>
  <literal externalValue="Centro Informaci&#xF3;n" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l6" name="Centro Informaci&#xF3;n"/>
  <literal externalValue="Desarrollo Corporativo" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l2" name="Desarrollo Corporativo"/>
  <literal externalValue="Enol" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l3" name="Enol"/>
  <literal externalValue="Pasivo" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l8" name="Pasivo"/>
  <literal externalValue="Producci&#xF3;n y Sistemas" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l1" name="Producci&#xF3;n y Sistemas"/>
  <literal externalValue="Proyectos" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l5" name="Proyectos"/>
  <literal externalValue="Servicios" id="com.ibm.team.workitem.enumeration.area.literal.l10" name="Servicios"/>
</enumeration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="enumeration/literal">
        <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <!-- this should be different, I tried with select="current()" too -->
      </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

try:

```
<xsl:template match="/enumeration">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="literal">
            <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```